# Excel copy cell A to cell C if cell B duplicate

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have two columns in excel with column A is a numbers and column B is a duplicate of various texts.

I need a way to copy the column A to column C if column B is duplicate?

Comment: Need to be clearer about what is expected to be a duplicate of what.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to indicate duplicates, would this work for your case (formula goes in `C2`)?

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B2)>1,A2,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Work on a copy, with data headers assumed to be in row 1.
Sort data by column B.

In C2, type `=IF(B2=B1,A1,"")`
and copy down the sheet.

Then, if there's a duplicate, it will appear in column C